# Why can't print to a network printer?

Tags: printer, troubleshooting, network-printer

In the office we have a Canon MF4570dn printer connected through a switch to the LAN. At the same switch there is a computer running Vista which regularly prints to this printer.

In the past, I was able to configure my Win 7 Printers and Faxes control panel to see this printer. I can see its properties pane and when entering its IP address, I can browse the printer's "Remote UI" management interface in the browser.

However, I cannot set this printer as the default printer, nor can I print a test page from the control panel. Additionally, I don't see this printer in the available printers list in the Print... menus of the various applications.

In the context sensitive menu for this printer in Control Panel, I see the Troubleshoot entry. But, when selecting it, I get the message that "Troubleshooting couldn't identify the problem."

How can I use this printer for printing over the network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what was the problem, but I downloaded the driver software from Canon's website and went through the installation process again. Now everything works as expected.